# How to setup swig installation in Windows for GRIDdb python client?

Tags: python, swig, griddb

I am trying to install SWIG after installing Cmake and Python for getting started with the GRIDdb python client on Windows. I am following the Cmake Build Guide For GridDB Python Client
https://griddb.org/python_client/cmake_build_guide.html
I downloaded swigwin-3.0.12 but it is not responding after extracting
Anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will resolve your problem:
I have created a new admin user in GridDB using the following command

```
gs_adduser gs#admin_user -p admin_user
```

Comment: Oh, That's great kind of you. I am going to try this. Thank you.